# Is it possible to add filters to a chart in R like powerbi?

Tags: r, filter, bar-chart, data-visualization, slicers

I have been creating a bar plot for the result of a sentiment analysis model in R. The data is very confidential feedbacks from the customers. So, the feedbacks are then fed into a sentiment analysis model to generate outputs. Using the output from the model I have generated a barplot using ggplot2.
[image]

I want to now apply filter based on the customers location like, customer belonging to which location is feeling angry or sad. Is it possible?

Comment: so why don't you explore it with a `facet_wrap(~location)` or make a heatmap `geom_tile(aes(sentiments, location, fill = count))` ?

Comment: Are you after applying this filter interactively? E.g. by means of a pull-down menu? If so, have a look at `shiny`; it is easy to create simple interactive application quickly. Otherwise, Stephan's suggestion is a good one.

Comment: thank you for the ideas. I'm choosing R-shiny as you mentioned it is easy to create